# Edit .exe in notepad

Tags: executable, notepad

When I view .exe files in notepad for example C:\WINDOWS\system32\attrib.exe I see the line
Attribute Utility
when I view the properties the value of File description is Attribute Utility, but when I edit it in notepad it turns it into a .COM file properties menu instead of a .exe. I tried this in edit.exe but it just didn't display the File Description. My goal is edit the File Description so It says anything even a one character change would be fine (Its a learning test thing).

Comment: Pro tip: if you're actually serious about editing binary files, use a hex editor. Regular editors don't handle null terminators (binary `0000000`) too well. You're probably corrupting that file without realizing it.

Comment: Now I know a bit of assembly langugage can I create a hex editor out of assembly (Sorry for being picky but I try not to use other programs)

Comment: Assembly is the most low level programming language but what hex editor would you use?

Comment: Depends on your needs. Check here for a comparison: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU CAN'T!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!